# Laravel duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' on notification table

Tags: laravel

sending notify to multiple user in looping and then it duplicate entry on Nofification table

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1a65083e-0061-49c7-afcb-e4658da6c887' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `notifications` (`id`, `type`, `data`, `read_at`, `notifiable_id`, `notifiable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ....
```

```
    foreach ($booking_fails as $booking) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
           $user->notify(new SendBookingFailNotification($user->employee, $booking));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Explain your question about what you want to achieve or having trouble.

Comment: the Id field of notifications table that was generated by laravel,it error like above when sending to multple person

Comment: Rather than looping, have you tried `Notification::send($users, new SendBookingFailNotification($user->employee, $booking));`? What's the outcome?

Comment: not yet test @Rehmat. I will test it now

Comment: @MengheangSok do a test like this, and don't pass `$user->employee` argument. You will have access to notifiable already in your notification.

Comment: @Rehmat it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, the solution was to change the type of "id" column in notifications migration file from `$table->increments('id');` to `$table->uuid('id')->primary();`. and after that you have to refresh migrations.

another way is to change the column from database directly to type "char" with Length=36

Comment: id is already has type char with length 36. But still facing "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for notifications table" issue. Is there anyother way to resolve this issue?